# Using dotnet core 7 for Web API but none of the MySQL database providers work with it

Tags: mysql, .net-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

No matter which nuget packages I use for MySQL provider I cannot get it to work. All of the Core versions are the same (7.0) and they're all out of box (recently created a new Web API project).

The project can perform CRUD operations with InMemory Db, but I've recently set up a Db in Linode and want to use some MySQL data provider. I've done extensive Googling and SO research and the most common issue is version mismatch, however, all my versions are 7.0 as you can see. I also tried using `MySql.EntityFrameworkCore` but encountered similar error. I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project as well multiple times.

I would assume that the database provider version doesn't also need to be 7.0 since it's its own package/library, so, what the heck am I missing?? This has been a roadblock for several days now and I feel like I've tried everything.... I just want to find a MySQL database provider so I can continue development.

*Error Message*

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void CoreTypeMappingParameters..ctor(System.Type, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion.ValueConverter, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, System.Func`3<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGenerator>)'.
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlBoolTypeMapping..ctor(String storeType, Nullable`1 dbType, Nullable`1 size)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlTypeMappingSource..ctor(TypeMappingSourceDependencies dependencies, RelationalTypeMappingSourceDependencies relationalDependencies, IMySqlOptions options)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
```

*Project Settings*

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="6.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` *prerelease* version `7.0.0-silver.1` for now. The official GA version will be released in a few days.